# Celery Scheduler FIFO queue

Tags: python, celery, celerybeat

I have a number of jobs (A,B,C) that start each morning via a schedule.
I have these sent to a single worker to make sure that A does not execute before B.

Sometimes job A might take longer, overlapping the scheduled start for B and C.

This then results in the jobs executing in order A, C, B.

I can do a workaround but was wondering whether if there was a FIFO for celery beat scheduler that I am missing?

Example code

```
'''
celery_scheduler.py
'''
from run_celery import celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
import redis

schedule={}
schedule.update(
    {
        'job-elasticache_task1': {
            'task': 'my_celery.celery_scripts.task1',
            'schedule': crontab(minute=30, hour=8, day_of_week='1-5'),
        },
        'job-elasticache_task2': {
            'task': 'my_celery.celery_scripts.task2',
            'schedule': crontab(minute=35, hour=8, day_of_week='1-5'),
        },
        'job-elasticache_task3': {
            'task': 'my_celery.celery_scripts.task3',
            'schedule': crontab(minute=40, hour=8, day_of_week='1-5'),
        },
    }
)

'''
run_celery.py
'''
from celery import Celery
celery_task_list = ['my_celery.celery_scripts']

def makecelery(celery=None):
    celery = Celery(
        'mytasks', 
        broker="rediss://{connection_string}", 
        include=celery_task_list)
       
    '''prefetch one at a time'''
    celery.conf.task_acks_late = True
    celery.conf.worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1
    
    '''dedicated worker monitoring of dashboard data task refreshes'''
    celery.conf.task_routes = {
        'my_celery.celery_scripts.*':{'queue' : 'my_queue'},
}


    '''find any random tasks added'''
    celery.autodiscover_tasks()

    return celery

celery = makecelery()
```

Comment: you should add some parts of your code, because it doesn't sound like FIFO, if they can race themselves

Comment: FIFO is working if I push jobs, it is just celery beat does jobs closest to current time first.   Is this not the normal expected approach?  In relation to code, I dont have too much configured other than     celery.conf.task_acks_late = True
celery.conf.worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1

Comment: You said you are having an issue, but you also need to provide with the exact steps you are making. Please edit your question to display this information.